# Pandas: merge two dataframe of different sizes on one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My first dataframe (df1) looks like this:

```
      pvalue    trend               time                
0   0.000065    0.000076    2019-03-18 04:00:04 
1   0.000087    0.000098    2019-03-18 04:00:06 
2   0.000000    0.000000    2019-03-18 04:00:22 
3   0.000000    0.000087    2019-03-18 04:02:29 
4   0.000000    0.000000    2019-03-18 04:03:04
5   0.000000    0.000023    2019-03-18 04:03:05 
6   0.000000    0.000000    2019-03-18 04:03:18 
7   0.000000    0.000067    2019-03-18 04:18:55 
8   0.000000    0.000000    2019-03-18 04:18:56 
9   0.000000    0.000000    2019-03-18 04:20:41
```

My second data (df2) looks like that:

```
                time      price
0   2019-03-18 04:00:00  0.00190633
1   2019-03-18 04:00:01  0.00190633
2   2019-03-18 04:00:02  0.00190633
3   2019-03-18 04:00:03  0.00190633
4   2019-03-18 04:00:04  0.00190633
5   2019-03-18 04:00:05  0.00190633
6   2019-03-18 04:00:06  0.00190800
7   2019-03-18 04:00:07  0.00190800
8   2019-03-18 04:00:08  0.00190800
9   2019-03-18 04:00:09  0.00190800
```

`df2['time']` at each row, there is a change of one second. But on df1, there are some gaps between each `df1['time']` of a few seconds... what I would like to have is the following:

```
                time      price     pvalue  trend
0   2019-03-18 04:00:00 0.00190633 0.000000 0.000000
1   2019-03-18 04:00:01 0.00190633 0.000000 0.000000
2   2019-03-18 04:00:02 0.00190633 0.000000 0.000000
3   2019-03-18 04:00:03 0.00190633 0.000000 0.000000
4   2019-03-18 04:00:04 0.00190633 0.000065 0.000076
5   2019-03-18 04:00:05 0.00190633 0.000000 0.000000
6   2019-03-18 04:00:06 0.00190800 0.000087 0.000098
```

So basically have all the seconds and when there is data at pvalue and trend in df1 put them in the new dataframe. What I tried is the following: `df_all =df_pvalue_trade.merge(df_check,on='time',left_index=True)` but I only have the rows of df1, not every seconds like in my example... any idea? thanks!

The result I have with the above tried code is the following:

```
pvalue  trend   time    mkt_result  price
6   0.000000    0.000000    2019-03-18 04:00:06 reject Ha := upward OR downward trend   0.00190800
21  0.000000    0.000000    2019-03-18 04:00:21 reject Ha := upward OR downward trend   0.00190800
22  0.000000    0.000000    2019-03-18 04:00:22 reject Ha := upward OR downward trend   0.00190800
149 0.000000    0.000000    2019-03-18 04:02:29 reject Ha := upward OR downward trend   0.00190594
184 0.000000    0.000000    2019-03-18 04:03:04 reject Ha := upward OR downward trend   0.00190594
185 0.000000    0.000000    2019-03-18 04:03:05 reject Ha := upward OR downward trend   0.00190594
198 0.000000    0.000000    2019-03-18 04:03:18 reject Ha := upward OR downward trend   0.00190594
```

Which is not what I want...

Comment: df_pvalue_trade.merge(df_check,on='time',left_index=True,how='left')

Comment: @Wen-Ben, nope it gives me the same result as my line of code... could you erase that market duplicate please? thanks

Comment: Change the how= left to 'right' ?

Comment: @Viktor.w - For me working like your expected output - `df = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='time', how='left').fillna(0)`

Comment: @Wen-Ben, nope, then I have no value in the column `pvalue, trend, time`

Comment: @jezrael, the first one is the right one, and your piece of code works thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='time', how='left').fillna(0)
print (df)
                 time     price    pvalue     trend
0 2019-03-18 04:00:00  0.001906  0.000000  0.000000
1 2019-03-18 04:00:01  0.001906  0.000000  0.000000
2 2019-03-18 04:00:02  0.001906  0.000000  0.000000
3 2019-03-18 04:00:03  0.001906  0.000000  0.000000
4 2019-03-18 04:00:04  0.001906  0.000065  0.000076
5 2019-03-18 04:00:05  0.001906  0.000000  0.000000
6 2019-03-18 04:00:06  0.001908  0.000087  0.000098
7 2019-03-18 04:00:07  0.001908  0.000000  0.000000
8 2019-03-18 04:00:08  0.001908  0.000000  0.000000
9 2019-03-18 04:00:09  0.001908  0.000000  0.000000
```

Also if need replace `NaN`s only columns from `df1.columns` which are different like `df2.columns`:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df1.columns.difference(df2.columns), 0)
print (d)
{'pvalue': 0, 'trend': 0}

df = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='time', how='left').fillna(d)
print (df)
                 time     price    pvalue     trend
0 2019-03-18 04:00:00  0.001906  0.000000  0.000000
1 2019-03-18 04:00:01  0.001906  0.000000  0.000000
2 2019-03-18 04:00:02  0.001906  0.000000  0.000000
3 2019-03-18 04:00:03  0.001906  0.000000  0.000000
4 2019-03-18 04:00:04  0.001906  0.000065  0.000076
5 2019-03-18 04:00:05  0.001906  0.000000  0.000000
6 2019-03-18 04:00:06  0.001908  0.000087  0.000098
7 2019-03-18 04:00:07  0.001908  0.000000  0.000000
8 2019-03-18 04:00:08  0.001908  0.000000  0.000000
9 2019-03-18 04:00:09  0.001908  0.000000  0.000000
```